# Gui Program compiling error

Tags: java, user-interface, compilation

I'm trying to make a bit of code that has a gui that gets the GCD of of 2 numbers. I keep getting an error when I try to compile my code

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Gooie.Gooie
Java Result: 1\
```

Can someone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong?

my code

```
package Gooie;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gooie {
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new GcdFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
class GcdFrame extends JFrame {
public GcdFrame() {
setTitle("Greatest Common Divisor Finder");
centerWindow(this);
setSize(267, 200);
//setResizable(false);
setResizable(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel panel = new GcdPanel();
this.add(panel);
}

private void centerWindow(Window w) {
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
setLocation((d.width - w.getWidth()) / 2,
        (d.height - w.getHeight()) / 2);
}
}

class GcdPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JTextField xTextField, yTextField,
    gcdTextField;
private JLabel xLabel, yLabel, gcdLabel;
private JButton calculateButton, exitButton;

public GcdPanel() {
// display panel
JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
// displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
// payment label
xLabel = new JLabel("X:");
displayPanel.add(xLabel);

// payment text field
xTextField = new JTextField(10);
displayPanel.add(xTextField);

// rate label
yLabel = new JLabel("Y:");
displayPanel.add(yLabel);

// rate text field
yTextField = new JTextField(10);
displayPanel.add(yTextField);


// future value label
gcdLabel = new JLabel("GCD:");
displayPanel.add(gcdLabel);

// future value text field
gcdTextField = new JTextField(10);
gcdTextField.setEditable(false);
gcdTextField.setFocusable(false);
displayPanel.add(gcdTextField);

// button panel
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

// calculate button
calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
buttonPanel.add(calculateButton);

// exit button
exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
exitButton.addActionListener(this);
buttonPanel.add(exitButton);

// add panels to main panel
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Object source = e.getSource();
if (source == exitButton)
    System.exit(0);
else if (source == calculateButton) {
    int x =  Integer.parseInt(xTextField.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(yTextField.getText());
    int gcd = greatestCommonDivisor(x, y);
    gcdTextField.getText();
}

}
private int greatestCommonDivisor(int x, int y) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

while (x != y) {
    if (x > y) {
        x = x - y;
    } else {
        y = y - x;
    }
}
return y;
}

}
```

Comment: What are you using to compile this program?

Comment: Have you tried performing a clean and build?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your program in Eclipse and it seems to run fine....no errors ! Download IDE such as eclipse  or anything that you like and try to run the program from there.

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
- https://netbeans.org/

[image]

Comment: im using netbeans and getting this error, its really annoying lol

Comment: @Saint it has to do with your package...can you post the directory structure image of your project ?

Comment: I managed to figure it out, thank you for your help. I ended up deleting the main class and starting a new project and that seemed to clear up the problem, no idea why though lol

Comment: @Saint no problem. If you find the answer useful in anyways please give a vote up /+1. Thanks and take care